# Jquery selecting multiple radio-inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose I have two radio inputs, with name `radio-1` and `radio-2`, I am storing their inputs in an object which I will finally use as json to make a post request.

```
  vals = {}
  $('input:radio[name=radio-1]').click(function() {
  vals['radio-1'] = $('input:radio[name=radio-1]:checked').val();
  });
  $('input:radio[name=radio-2]').click(function() {
  vals['radio-2'] = $('input:radio[name=radio-2]:checked').val();
  });
```

Which generates for example: `val = {'radio-1':1,'radio-2':3}`

Now, say I have multiple radio inputs, `radio-3`, `radio-355`. etc... I want to be able put all the values of `radio-[0-9]+` into my `val` dictionary without having to write code like above for each of them.

The pseudocode I have in mind is:

1. Find all radio's with names `radio-[0-9]+` which have been clicked
2. add their values to `vals` dictionary with name as key

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use jQuery [`attribute starts with selector`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) to write click event for all radio elements with name starts with `radio`. Try this:

```
$('input:radio[name^=radio]').click(function() {
  vals[$(this).attr("name")] = $(this).val();
 });
```

Comment: must be `^=` not `=^`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do it

```
// base object
var myObj = {};

// all radio inputs with a name attribute that starts with radio-
$('input[type="radio"][name*="radio-"]').click(function() {
    // cache your jquery wrapped `this`
    var $this = $(this);
    // push the radio inputs value onto object with $this' name attribute as the key
    myObj[$this.attr('name')] = $this.val();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/OxyDesign/z6jm8v83/

JS

```
var vals = {},
    radios = $('input[name^=radio]'),
    radiosLgth = radios.length;

radios.click(function() {
    vals = {};
    for(var i = 0; i < radiosLgth; i++){
        var radioElt = radios.eq(i),
            isChecked = radioElt.is(':checked');
        if(isChecked) vals[radioElt.attr('name')] = radioElt.val();
    }
});
```

On each click it makes a new object with all the name/value of each radio checked.

Comment: thanks a lot. A little curious, why did you declare vals inside the callback again?

Comment: It's not a new declaration (no var keyword) it's a new assignation because if you don't do that your object keep the previous values and if one of your radio is no more checked it keep the value in the object. I don't know if my explanations are really clear.

Comment: I mean : if you click the first one, you add the first value, if the first value is unchecked (by another script) and then you click the second one, if you didn't assign a new object you will have an object with first and second values instead of just the second one.